# Node JS app crashes after two clients access it . Odd behavior

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

My project consists in an API that stores information sent from an application(AppA) in php, and has an admin/management front end in Angularjs.

Problem is that after sending information from AppA when I try to access to the frontend and check that information, *the backend acts weirdly*, It throws errors that can't be replicated(meaning that the same information will not throw the error again) or will get into infinite loops.

The backend app uses Expressjs and has several endpoints for both processes using mainly **OOP** and it connects to a mongodb database using mongoose.

It uses a lot of async/await bits in order to validate information with the database ( This because of  dynamic structures (including the one portraited in the request) which are extracted from the database ), even some literal Promises are used in order to use "async" getters and setters.

This dynamic structure makes necessary the use of recursive functions (which sometimes break and causes those infinite loops, I'm guessing at this point) , which would destructure data(like objects or arrays)  into simpler ones (like strings or objectIds).

There are a few static methods ( 4 total in just one class) but they only access themself, no static information whatsoever.

*These errors are inpredictable* meaning that do not occur 100% after the previous mentioned events , so i find it difficult to trace them but have found out that they appear mainly(not sure if completly) when these two clients access.

When an error occurs I have to restart the app and the same information from the previous request do not throw any error this time.

Comment: I think, you have forgotten to ask a question. And even if you asked one, how do you think anybody could help you with the information you are giving us?

Comment: As you might be able to tell I am a complete beginner and thought maybe there are clear things I'm not seeing, if you may, could you tell me what extra information might be useful ?

Comment: for instance some of the errors that are thrown (error message + stacktrace) and the code at the respective locations